# Keep branch of tree list

Tags: jquery

There is a tree style structure from which I want to keep only a specific branch.

The list is like:

```
ul.level-1
--li
----ul.level-2
------li
------li
--li
----ul.level-2
------li
------li
------li
```

By giving the element I've selected (a second level `li` element), I want to remove all top level `li` **except** the one this `li` belongs to.

Is this possible without iterating within the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do what you need:

```
$('li.selected').closest('li.toplevel').siblings('li').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest("ul.level-1").children("li").filter(function() {
        return !$this.closest(this).length;
    }).remove();
});
```

First, [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used to match the top-level `<ul>` element. Then for each of its children `<li>` elements, [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is used with `closest()` to check if the clicked `<li>` element is a descendant of the current list item, or that list item itself. This excludes the clicked item's branch, and [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) is called on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.level2 li').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('li').siblings().remove()
})
```

Comment: this will not work, as .parent() will point to <ul.level-2> not <li>

Comment: @tborychowski Yours doesn't work as there is no element with class of `top-level` in OP's markup.

Comment: Well there should be. This was a hidden tip :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/tHT42/)

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("li").siblings().remove();
});​
```